# Display PDF viewer inside the Google Apps Script Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I want to display a PDF inside a Dialog of a Google Spreadsheet Add-on Dialog.

more about apps script dialog can be found here

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/01/540cb75550adf33f281f29132dddd14fded85bfc.pdf"  frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

When I inspect, I see the message **Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/01/540cb75550adf33f281f29132dddd14fded85bfc.pdf".**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can embed the Google viewer to display the PDF using an `<iframe>`.*

#### Code:

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/01/540cb75550adf33f281f29132dddd14fded85bfc.pdf&embedded=true" height="1080" width="1920"></iframe>
```

Just make sure to change the `height` and `width` attributes of the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Failed to load 'https://www.w3docs.com/uploads/media/default/0001/01/540cb75550adf33f281f29132dddd14fded85bfc.pdf' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.

Comment: Try without the `<object>` and just set the size of the iframe. I've updated my code.