# Google Drive embedder issue

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

Is there a Google Drive embedder that can open different files within the iframe itself, instead of redirecting to the google drive on a new tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display PDF viewer inside the Google Apps Script Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203813/display-pdf-viewer-inside-the-google-apps-script-dialog)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo no cuz I'm already able to view folders, but if a click a folder itll redirect me to google drive, I want the iframe to adjust and automatically change id's to the folder i clicked and so on. So the user doesn't have a google drive tab get open